# Defining and processing high-level DevOps events

Tags: automation, integration

Every CI tool defines more or less "their" view on how integration and delivery can work, and every DevOps team (re)invents their specific way to support the business using these tools.

But, how could you to define and execute high-level business logic?

Here are two examples from daily work:

- A feature branch get merged into develop branch, followed by a successful build and a deployment via Docker Swarm, followed by a series of automated acceptance tests. High-level business event: you can take a record of an upstream feature increment. How to aggregate those low-level events to the high-level event?
- Or, imagine a CI system is going to start a complex build. From previous statistics, it "knows" that the build requires many resources. Could this system be able to issue a resources request to the underlying elastic cloud environment and acquire additional CPU/RAM just for the time of the build?

Comment: Just a hint: it is quite unclear to me what you are asking in the first question. The answer to the second question is so obviously "yes" that I think I am missing something. You might consider reformulating/expanding on both questions.